# How to import a txt in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, bulkinsert

I have `.txt` files with contents like this:

```
31/03/2014|4|0|987.83|0.0|4|0|952502|
```

The columns are delimited by `|`, but after the last data I have another `|`.

When I tried importing with this code:

```
bulk insert [201404]
from 'C:\Martin\TARSHOP\Auditoría\201406\Archivos Recibidos\04_2014.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '|'
)
```

I get an error message, but when I change the file and delete the last `|` in the file, I can import it perfectly.

How can I change the code to import automatically without changing the file always?

Comment: i think you should modify query ROWTERMINATOR = ' \n'

Comment: You can use SSIS which will give you more control over the import process, allowing you to ignore the last |

Comment: ROWTERMINATOR = '|\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BULK INSERT [201404]
   FROM 'C:\Martin\TARSHOP\Auditoría\201406\Archivos Recibidos\04_2014.txt'

   WITH 
      (
         FIELDTERMINATOR =' |',
         ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n'
      );
```